# Scale image to fit div

Tags: css

I want to scale the picture to fit the main div class

http://jsfiddle.net/EyW99/

Sorry, forgot to mention that I need it to work in IE8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `background-size:contain` CSS property.

```
.image {
    background: url('http://astridterese.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/google.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

If you need to support old browsers (namely IE on Windows XP and below, since Vista and 7 users should be on IE9), use an `<img>` tag instead, as this causes the browser to scale the image to the dimensions you specify either in CSS height/width or the HTML attributes of the tag.

`<img class="image" src="http://astridterese.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/google.jpg" />`

Comment: That doesn't work on IE8 so I guess it'll rule it out as a viable option for most things.

Comment: If I set something like this in the backend <img class="image" /> is there a way to set the url in css ?

Comment: You can't unfortunately, you would need to use javascript to set the tags src property.

Comment: background-size: contain; definitely doesn't work - it makes the DIV bigger to fit the image.

Comment: The `background-size:contain` property has no effect on the dimensions of a `div`. Only the background image within it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update version of the fiddle that makes use of the CSS3 property `background-size`: http://jsfiddle.net/EyW99/2/

What you need to add to your styling is basically `background-size: contain;` to make the browser scale the image to the largest possible size of the image that still fits within your element, or `background-size:X% X%;` or `background-size:Xpx Xpx;` if you want to controll the sizing yourself.

**Note**

As background-size is a CSS3 property, it has limited browser support.

IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.

**Cross-browser soultion**

This solution is maybe not as "nice" as the new CSS-property, but for cross-browser support you could change your `div` to an `img`, which will allow the browser to resize the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
.main{
    height: 113px;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.image {
    background: url('http://astridterese.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/google.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

That works in Chrome but not IE8 so is probably useless.

Personally, I'd change the inner div to an image tag with it's width and height set to 100%.
​

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a pure CSS solution, you can use JavaScript for a solution that works on all major browsers. The [bgStretcher](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html) plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will do what you want and will adjust the size dynamically if the size of the div changes.